# Are any more details on the September 5, 2007 "Ares-1X Steel Rod Mishap During Static Strip Test at KSC Parachute Refurbishment Facility" available?

Tags: history, safety, parachute, shuttle-derived

The presentation [Recurring Themes from Human Spaceflight Mishaps During Flight Tests and Early Operations](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20160009174/downloads/20160009174.pdf) contains several rather "hinty" references to a mishap that occurred in September 2007 during testing of the parachute for the ill-fated Ares 1-X mission.

- "...a ground crew fatality was narrowly
  avoided during preparations for the Ares
  1-X test flight in the Parachute
  Refurbishment Facility at KSC."
- "Ares-1X: Even though the parachute riser lines were approximately 4 times longer
  than the riser lines on the Shuttle's drag chute, there was no requirement for
  engineering to perform a first-time GSE DE loads analysis of the test set-up or a
  readiness review for the initial Area-1X parachute static strip test."
- "Ares-1X: The initial Ares I-X strip test set-up combined components (forklift, a
  capstan winch, nylon break ties, and a nylon towline) in an untested combination.
  The nylon towline used to extract the parachute released a dangerous amount of
  stored energy upon failure."

Some images are also included:

[image]

Is there any narrative description, or most desirably, a mishap report, explaining exactly what went on here?

Comment: sounds like they pulled on a parachute using a strap & the strap broke--cable/tiedown failure is super dangerous & a common issue in any warehouse or transportation job; this incident just happened to be related to hardware testing in the space program!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some digging I could find a [presentation](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20160009174/downloads/20160009174.pdf) that has references to the mishap.
It also had the URL of the [Nasa Safety Centre](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/hq/nsc) where I could find the [report](https://archive.org/download/recurring-causes-of-human-spaceflight-mishaps-during-flight-tests-and-early-operations/recurring-causes-of-human-spaceflight-mishaps-during-flight-tests-and-early-operations.pdf), the presentation is probably based upon.

Chapter 7.1.7 on page 19 of that report you can find a short version that doesn't tell a lot of new stuff.
[image: Screeshot from the Report] here, the [ref. 15] made me suspicious.

And really, on Page 109 of the report they dissect the chain of events and causes in great detail! Have fun reading!

Comment: First link is the same presentation linked in the question. The link to the full document is gold! As you say Appendix H, while pretty repetitive, gives the details. Many thanks.

Comment: Oh ***... I overlooked the link in the question, my bad!

Comment: Those NASA accidents are a really nice example of "Hindsight is 20/20"! Like:"What sane person would think that pure oxygen at 1.3 atmosphere in a closed envoiremnt would be a good idea?" or "Putting pressure on a contractor to retreat from his warning is a bad idea"... It all seems SO obvious in hindsight! But it wasn't back than!

Answer (score 0):

For details, see "Recurring Causes of Human Spaceflight Mishaps during Flight Tests and Early Operations," NASA/TM-2020-220573 NESC-RP-12-00823, available from NASA STI Program / Mail Stop 148, NASA Langley Research Center. Hampton, VA 23681-2199

Comment: That sounds like a good reference, but you need to put some of the information requested in your answer to make it a good stack exchange answer.  Otherwise it's not much use.  Suppose I went through the trouble of obtaining that document, and it turns out there's nothing relevant in it?